# Problema al mostrar gráfica

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un conjunto de datos y necesito que el usuario establezca un intervalo de datos "válidos" según su propio criterio, para trabajar con ellos posteriormente. Para ello, muestro una representación gráfica de los datos donde se puede ver su comportamiento. Es decir, el usuario ve el gráfico y después le dice al programa sobre qué intervalo quiere trabajar.

El problema es el siguiente:

- Ejecuto el programa completo:

  - Al llegar a la representación gráfica `grp.lines_fast(xy)`se abre la ventana del plot, no dibuja nada y se queda colgada "pensando".
  - Después ejecuta `start = eval(input())` y la ventana del gráfico sigue "pensando".
  - Introduzco por teclado lo requerido en `start = eval(input())`,`stop = eval(input())` y `step = eval(input())` y finalmente el gráfico se dibuja.
  - La ejecución del código sigue su funcionamiento con normalidad.
- Ejecuto el programa línea a línea:

  - Al llegar a la representación gráfica `grp.lines_fast(xy)` el gráfico aparece dibujado y sin problemas.
  - El resto del código funciona sin problemas.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de lograr mi objetivo?

El código es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from scipy import optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import f02_graphs as grp
import f06_directories as drc
import f08_adjustments as adj


# Pedimos al usuario que introduzca el directorio en el que se encuentra el
# archivo que contiene los datos.
direct = drc.assembling_direct_arch()

# Copiamos los datos del archivo en listas.
# Abrimos el archivo.
csvarchive = open(direct)
# Leemos todos los registros.
data = csv.reader(csvarchive)

# Creamos las listas en las que almacenar los datos de cada columna.
x = []
y = []

# Guardamos las columnas segunda y tercera en una lista cada una.
for row in data:
    # Leemos la i-esima fila y comprobamos si esta vacia.
    if not row:
        continue
    # Guardamos cada elemento en una variable.
    element_01, element_02, element_03 = row
    # Asignamos cada variable a su lista.
    x.append(float(element_02))
    y.append(float(element_03))

# Cerramos el archivo.
csvarchive.close()

# Representamos los datos.
axis = list(range(0, len(x), 1))
xy = (axis, x, axis, y)
grp.lines_fast(xy)

# Pedimos por teclado un intervalo de datos sobre los que trabajar.
start = eval(input('Introduzca el punto inicial del intervalo de datos '
                   + 'sobre el que quiere trabajar:\n'))

stop = eval(input('Introduzca el punto final del intervalo de datos '
                  + 'sobre el que quiere trabajar:\n'))
# Pedimos por teclado el tamaño de step.
step = eval(input('Introduzca el el tamaño de paso (usualmente se ' +
                  'corresponde con el numero de datos que adquiere el ' +
                  'PSED en cada muestreo, 500):\n'))

# A partir de aquí el código sigue funcionando sin problemas.
```

EDIT:

La función `lines_fast()`:

```
def lines_fast(L):
    """
    Representa en forma de linea y de la forma mas simple, todas las
    listas de datos que se pasen como parametro.

    L: list
        Listas de datos de los ejes x e y en forma de pares
        x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3.
    """
    #
    n_data = len(L)
    if (n_data % 2) != 0:
        print("El numero de elementos xi,yi no es par.\n")
        return None
    #
    plt.figure()
    #
    for i in range(0, n_data, 2):
        plt.plot(L[i], L[i+1])
    #
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.axis('tight')
    #
    plt.show()
    #
    return None
```

Comment: `input` es bloqueante posiblemente no se quede "pensando" simplemente se queda congelado y esperando a causa del `input` como cualquier GUI con el mainloop bloqueado. ¿Cómo implementas `grp.lines_fast`? PD: el uso de `eval` para entradas de usuario es peligroso y una mala práctica por lo general dado que evalúa cualquier código Python válido, si son enteros o floats deberías hacer un casting no usar `eval`.

Comment: @FJSevilla He editado el mensaje para añadir la función `lines_fast`. Respecto a usar `eval()`, tenía entendido que en Python 3 era necesario para recoger valores numéricos introducidos por teclado.